# Lovasz theta function integrality

Tags: graph-theory

Is anything known about Lovasz Theta Function taking integral value in non-perfect graphs? In particular, does integral value of Lovasz theta always coincide with the size of largest independent set?

For instance, graph below is non-perfect, and its Lovasz theta function gives the independence number.

[image]
[(source)](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/save/non-perfect.png)

Its true for a few other non-perfect graphs I tried, here's a [Mathematica package](http://mathematica-bits.blogspot.com/2011/03/computing-lovasz-theta-function.html)  I used to compute it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. For some examples see [When the Lovász theta-function saturates its upper bound](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46534/when-the-lovasz-theta-function-saturates-its-upper-bound)